# 正規表現で複数行にまたがる角括弧に囲まれた部分を除外して、マッチさせたい

Tags: javascript, 正規表現

javascriptで、下記のようなテキストから [ と ] に囲まれていない部分の"。"で終わる文を正規表現で取得したいと考えています。

```
あいうえお
[
あいうえお。
かきくけこ。
]
こんにちは。
さようなら。
hello
```

試した方法は、[]内にマッチする正規表現パターンを否定先読みで除外するという方法で、以下のように書きましたが、結果は[]内の
あいうえお。かきくけこ。
にもマッチしてしまいました。

```
/^(?!\[[\s\S]*?\]).*?。$/gm
```

目的を満たすにはどのように書けばよいのでしょうか？

Comment: \[ と \] がネストする可能性はありますか？

Comment: あらかじめ [ と ] の間に挟まれた部分を削除してから判定するアプローチもあるかなと思いました。

Comment: ネストはないです。cubickさんの方法で試してみます。

Answer (score 2):

フラグに`m`を指定しているため、`^$`が行頭と行末に一致します。
なのでご質問の`/^(?!\[[\s\S]*?\]).*?。$/gm`は否定先読みとは関係なく、行末に`。`のない全ての行にヒットしています。
例えば`]`を`]。`に書き換えることで、その行もヒットしてしまいます。

複数行の`[]`を除外しながら各行末の`。`を判定するのは厳しいです。
@cubick さんのコメントのようにまずは`m`フラグを使わずに括弧を除外してから、改めて`m`フラグで各行のマッチを取得する方法が、目的を満たすには相応しい書き方だと思います。

```js
var s = "あいうえお\r\n" +
"[\r\n" +
"あいうえお。\r\n" +
"かきくけこ。\r\n" +
"]\r\n" +
"こんにちは。\r\n" +
"さようなら。\r\n" +
"hello";
r = s.replace(/^([\s\S]*)\[[\s\S]*\]([\s\S]*)$/, "$1$2");
m = r.match(/^.+。$/gm);
console.log(m);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。その方法で試してみます。

Answer (score 2):

こんな感じでしょうか。

```js
var s = 
"はじめまして。\n" +
"あいうえお\n" +
"[\n" +
"あいうえお。\n" +
"かきくけこ。\n" +
"]\n" +
"こんにちは。\n" +
"[\n" +
"たちつてと。\n" +
"]\n" +
"さようなら。\n" +
"hello";
var regex = /(?<!\[[^\]]*)^[^\[\]]*。$/gm;
var match = s.match(regex);
console.log(match);
```

「`[`の後、`]`が現れないままだとダメ」と言うのを否定先読みで表現しています。

単純な例では動いている(Safariでは否定先読みは動きませんでしたが…)と思うんですが、「`[` と `]` の間に挟まれた部分を削除」と言う方がわかりやすくて良さそうに思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ブラウザによって動かないのは避けたいので [ と ] の間に挟まれた部分を削除する方法を試してみます。